# Can a secondary Switch profile access their save data from a game purchased by the main account if they buy the game for themselves?

Tags: nintendo-switch

Specifically I bought Pokemon Violet with my main profile. My girlfriend started her own save on her profile. I'm getting a new Switch and plan on transferring my account and profile to the new Switch. I understand she can't access the game on her own profile after that, but will her save still be on her profile on that original Switch and if she buys her own copy of the game will she still be able to access her save?

I've already made her her own Nintendo account and linked the profile so this won't be an issue for whatever games she wants to buy and play in the future.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is by no means complete, but here's some testing from my own experience.

Setup:

- I have a switch that I share with my housemates. It's registered as my "primary switch"
- My parents have a switch that I have an account on.
- I have NSO. Nobody else has it.
- I've got LoZ SS as a digital game, BotW and MK8 as cartridges, and all DLC associated with each of the above games.

---

Effects:

- I can access games, DLC, and save data from both switches.
- My housemates can access games I've purchased through the store (tested using LoZ SS) as well as DLC associated with a physical card (tested using BotW) on our switch.
- My parents can access DLC associated with a physical card (tested using MK8) on their switch, *while it is connected to the internet*.

From what I can tell, you can set a particular switch as the "primary" for a user, and then all other users on that switch can use its games whether or not the switch is online. Other, "secondary" switches require a network connection.

Comment: Thanks for the testing. I don't plan on doing a primary/non-primary situation just to keep it even more simple.

Comment: Unfortunately, Nintendo makes you set one of your switches as "primary" even if you use them both equally, if that makes any sense.